# how to typedef annotation in Java

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, annotations

I have a group of methods that have very similar annotations declaration, how to shorten them? Not to repeat them everywhere?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/relative_path", 
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        consumes = "appilcation/json",
        produces = "appilcation/json")
@ResponseBody
public User method1(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                  @RequestBody String requestBody)
{...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a spring meta-annotation for that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/relative_path", 
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    consumes = "appilcation/json",
    produces = "appilcation/json")
@ResponseBody
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}
```

and use it on your method:

```
@MyAnnotation
public User method1(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                  @RequestBody String requestBody) { }
```

Solution:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = "appilcation/json",
        produces = "appilcation/json")
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/relative_path")
@MyAnnotation
public User method1(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                  @RequestBody String requestBody) { }
```

Comment: but how to do it if "value = "/relative_path" " changes ? Thanks

Comment: @hardbone I guess there is no way. I'll try to find if any though.

Comment: Actually it is doable, jus put two annotations on one method. See above. Thanks a lot Rohit!!!